# What is the value "a" here, and what does it represent?

Tags: random-variables

[Here](https://ibb.co/VmDCcTN) is a couple of paragraphs about Regression Lines and Linear Equations in graphs.  It concludes with

A line that “best ﬁts” the data can then be drawn through the scatter diagram. This line is called the regression line, and it can be used to produce a linear equation, **y = bx + a**, that describes the approximate relation between IQ score (x) and GPA (y).

I can follow everything up until the "a".  What would be the value of it here, and what could it be representing?

Thank you!

Matha Maticallycha Llenged

[image: a few paragraphs about the main idea]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ is the $y$-intercept.

It is the predicted value of $y$ when $x=0$, that is the GPA when the IQ is $0$.

Comment: Can't quite follow.  Can you illustrate at all?

Comment: $y=bx+a$ is a straight line (the blue line), here $a$ and $b$ are value that would determine the line. $b$ is the slope and $a$ is the intercept.  If the IQ is $100$, then the GPA is predicted to be $100b+a$. If the IQ is $50$, then the GPA is predicted to be $50b+a$. If the IQ is $0$, then the GPA is predicted to be $0\cdot b + a=a$.

Comment: VERY grateful!  THANK YOU!! :)))